# Set and Get of a large amount of data

Tags: solidity, remix, dapps, database, uint256

I created a contract that insert one number (uint) in blockchain with set function but how can i retrieve all numbers inserted?

This is my html, i put 1 number in a blockchain and i will see just the last inserted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

window.onload = function () {
// check to see if user has metamask addon installed on his browser. check to make sure web3 is defined
if (typeof web3 === 'undefined') {
document.getElementById('metamask').innerHTML = 'You need <a href="https://metamask.io/">MetaMask</a> browser plugin to run this example'
}
// call the getvalue function here
getvalue();
}
//function to retrieve the last inserted value on the blockchain
function getvalue() {
try {
// contract Abi defines all the variables,constants and functions of the smart contract. replace with your own abi
var abi = []
//contract address. please change the address to your own
var contractaddress = '';
//instantiate and connect to contract address via Abi
var myAbi = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var myfunction = myAbi.at(contractaddress);
//call the get function of our SimpleStorage contract
myfunction.get.call(function (err, xname) {
if (err) { console.log(err) }
if (xname) {
//display value on the webpage
document.getElementById("xbalance").innerHTML = "primo: " + xname;

}
});
}
catch (err) {
document.getElementById("xbalance").innerHTML = err;
}
}

function setvalue() {
try {
// contract Abi defines all the variables,constants and functions of the smart contract. replace with your own abi
var abi = []
//contract address. please change the address to your own
var contractaddress = '';
//instantiate and connect to contract address via Abi
var myAbi = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var myFunction= myAbi.at(contractaddress);
//call the set function of our SimpleStorage contract
myFunction.set.sendTransaction(document.getElementById("xvalue").value,  { from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4000000 }, function (error, result) {
if (!error) {
console.log(result);
} else {
console.log(error);
}
})
} catch (err) {
document.getElementById("xvalue").innerHTML = err;
}
}

</script>
<center>
<div id="metamask" class="container"></div>
<h3>Inserimento dati nella Blockchain Ethereum</h3>
<br />
<table class="table">
                <div id="xbalance" class="container"></div>

                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Inserisci token: </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td><input id="xvalue" type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                  <td><input id="Button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="setvalue()" value="Add to Blockchain"  /></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And my contract is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract M {
    uint256 storeddata;

    function set(uint256 x) public {
        storeddata = x;
    }

    function get() public view returns(uint256) {
        return storeddata; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, edit your question to add the code of the contract so we can suggest an appropiate solution.

Comment: @Ismael just done

Answer (score 1):

Rob's answer is a good one. If you don't want to use events for some reason, you could:

- add your number to the uint array
- increment a `counter`

Then if you wanted to retrieve all the numbers, you would use the `counter` as your index for iterating over the array.

Comment: I also uploaded my first code, now i'm trying to use Rob's code and connect it to my contract from UI but i have some problems i think.

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, there is a dynamic array of `numbers` and the `appendNumber()` function just keeps adding to the list. The contract emits an event for every important state change which I strongly recommend.

A software client can observe and inspect several ways.

1. Subscribe/watch the event log. This facilitates construction of an offline representation of the state, since nothing can happen without a corresponding event. The client will always know the true state of the array without asking.
2. Inspect the `numbers()` function. It accepts one argument for `index` and returns one number. Iteration over the index is a client-side concern. I often add a helper function to return the array length to assist with this. Omitted for brevity, it would look like `function getCount() public view returns(uint count) { return numbers.length; }`
3. One could add a function to return an array of numbers. This is generally *not recommended* because the gas cost (processing) increases with scale. This would even make it impossible to use beyond a certain array size. Generally, this isn't necessary because the two alternatives above already address the concern.

-

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract SetGet {

    uint[] public numbers;

    event LogNewNumber(address setter, uint number);

    function appendNumber(uint value) public {
        numbers.push(value);
        emit LogNewNumber(msg.sender, value);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This example is perfect but i have some problems to connect this contract to User interface created using HTML and javascript, i don't know how to call event i think or i do it in a bad way.